# Pagination for MultiModel elasticsearch

Tags: ruby-on-rails, elasticsearch, pagination, will-paginate

I am performing a multi model elasticsearch in my controller and have not managed to get the results to paginate with the `will_paginate` gem.

In my controller I have:

```
def index
   @people = Elasticsearch::Model.search('*', [Authors, Editors])
end
```

Then in my view I have:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <% @people.each do |person| %>
      <tr>
        <td><%= person.name %></td>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<%= will_paginate @people, renderer: BootstrapPagination::Rails %>
```

The main error that keep getting is `undefined method 'total_pages' for #<Array:0x007fd8b0e32660>`.

Answer (score 2):

It's work for me:

```
@people = Elasticsearch::Model.search('', [Model1, Model2]).page(page).per(per_page).records
```

And the view

```
@people.results
```

Comment: Using Kaminari... will_paginate it's obsolete